# MySQL get only 30 messages on first run

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a code for chatrooms in php which works on long polling solution:

Here are some codes, I trimed some interface scripts:

client-side:

```
update_messages: function(){
    jQuery.post(quick_chat.ajaxurl, {
            action: 'quick-chat-ajax-update-messages',
            last_timestamp: quick_chat.last_timestamp,
            rooms: quick_chat.rooms,
            counter: quick_chat.updateMessageCounter
        },
        function(data) {
           if(data.success == 1) {
                var updates = data.messages;
                var main_container = jQuery('#dChatContainer > div.quick-chat-container');
                var chat_id = main_container.attr('data-quick-chat-id');
                var room_name = quick_chat.data[chat_id]['room_name'];
                var history_container = main_container.find('.quick-chat-history-container');

                for(var i=0;typeof(updates[i])!='undefined';i++){
                    if(room_name == updates[i].room) {
                       jQuery(history_container).prepend(quick_chat.single_message_html(updates[i], false));
                    }
                }


                quick_chat.last_timestamp = updates[updates.length-1].unix_timestamp;
            }
        }, 'json'
    );
}
```

and Server side:

```
public function update_messages_ajax_handler(){
    global $wpdb;
    $quick_chat_messages_table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'quick_chat_messages';

    ob_start();
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");

    $rooms = implode('", "', esc_sql((array)$_POST['rooms']));
    $counter = $_POST['counter'];
    $startTime = time();
    while((time()-$startTime)<=20){
        $sql = "
SELECT id
     , wpid
     , room
     , timestamp
     , UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) unix_timestamp
     , alias
     , status
     , message
     , color 
  FROM $quick_chat_messages_table_name
 WHERE room IN ('$rooms') 
   AND timestamp > FROM_UNIXTIME(".esc_sql($_POST['last_timestamp']).")
 ORDER 
    BY unix_timestamp ASC;
    ";



        $messages = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
        if($messages) {
            foreach($messages as $v){
                $v->timestring = date_i18n($this->date_format.' - '.$this->time_format, $v->unix_timestamp+$this->gmt_offset);
                $v->message = convert_smilies( $v->message );
            }
            $response = json_encode(array('no_participation' => $this->no_participation, 'success'=> 1, 'messages'=>$messages, 'counter'=>$counter));

            echo $response;
            ob_flush(); flush();
            exit;
        } else {
            sleep($this->options['timeout_refresh_messages']);
        }
    }

    $response = json_encode(array('no_participation' => $this->no_participation, 'success'=> 0, 'counter'=>$counter));

    echo $response;
    ob_flush(); flush();
    exit;
}
```

now, on first run (on load) I want to get only last 30 messages and then start polling.
I tried limiting the query but code just interates over.

How do I recreate this, to get only 30 messages and then get all new messages (without limit)

Comment: in SQL query, setting 'LIMIT 30', that would just get messages by 30, but all of them. I also had idea of setting condition when last_timestamp equals 0, but wanted to hear some ideas from professionals

Comment: The keyword is 'pagination', right?

Comment: @Strawberry well.. can be, but I don't want pages, I mean, load 30 and dont go down is okay

Comment: I see. So you want a UNION I guess.

Comment: probably, SQL is not my strongest side. but I'll google that now

Comment: from one glance, looks like totally different thing, from what I want. maybe I need to update my question to make it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example...

```
SELECT * FROM ints;
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
+---+
```

Let's say we want to get the first 3 values, as well as all remaining even numbers...

```
SELECT *  
  FROM 
     ( SELECT i FROM ints ORDER BY i LIMIT 3 )a 
 UNION 
     ( SELECT i FROM ints WHERE MOD(i,2) = 0);
 +---+
 | i |
 +---+
 | 0 |
 | 1 |
 | 2 |
 | 4 |
 | 6 |
 | 8 |
 +---+
```

Note the presence and absence of aliases. That's important but (I think) counter-intuitive.

Comment: Now it makes more sense but I will never implement this myself.

Comment: Here we use sqlfiddle - more useful for this kind of thing!

Comment: But, yeah that's the idea - although you probably don't want only messages with even timestamps!

Comment: I went with different solution since this is too complicated for me, but I accept this, since its seems more apropriate

Answer (score 0):

this is how I solved my problem

then I made double order

```
public function update_messages_ajax_handler(){
    global $wpdb;
    $quick_chat_messages_table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'quick_chat_messages';

    ob_start();
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");

    $rooms = implode('", "', esc_sql((array)$_POST['rooms']));
    $counter = $_POST['counter'];
    $startTime = time();
        while((time()-$startTime)<=20) {
            $sql = '(SELECT id, wpid, room, timestamp, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) AS unix_timestamp, alias, status, message, color FROM '
                                                    .$quick_chat_messages_table_name.' WHERE room IN ("'.$rooms.'") '
                                                    .' AND timestamp > FROM_UNIXTIME('.esc_sql($_POST['last_timestamp']).') '
                                                    .' ORDER BY unix_timestamp DESC LIMIT 30'
                                                    .') ORDER BY unix_timestamp ASC';

            $messages = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
            if($messages) {
                foreach($messages as $v){
                    $v->timestring = date_i18n($this->date_format.' - '.$this->time_format, $v->unix_timestamp+$this->gmt_offset);
                    $v->message = convert_smilies( $v->message );
                }
                $response = json_encode(array('no_participation' => $this->no_participation, 'success'=> 1, 'messages'=>$messages, 'counter'=>$counter));

                echo $response;
                ob_flush(); flush();
                exit;
            } else {
                sleep($this->options['timeout_refresh_messages']);
            }
        }


    $response = json_encode(array('no_participation' => $this->no_participation, 'success'=> 0, 'counter'=>$counter));

    echo $response;
    ob_flush(); flush();
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Got to get rid of all those 'stop-starts'. Completely unnecessary.

Comment: can you explain it more? this is the plugin I'm using, at thats how he implemented the long polling. Can you suggest more correct way?

Comment: It's fine. You just don't need to do this `.'` every time you start a new line.